# Git: Taking pull request from another feature branch

Tags: git, git-pull, feature-branch

From the git master branch, I created a new feature branch `feature_001`. I created one more feature branch from master, `feature_002`. After finishing, I am trying to pull `feature_001` changes in `feature_002` also.

How can I achieve this in git?

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout feature_002
git merge feature_001
```